# simulated annealing in python

Tags: python, simulated-annealing

I have a function called Cal_SINR which is returning a tuple what I need from it is variable called current_SINR and I am trying to apply a simulated annealing algorithm  to accept only bigger SINR values than current_SINR but it sometimes returns values that are less than the current and I don't know what is the problem.

Here is the code for the simulated annealing part:

```
temp = 100
min_temp = 1
cooling = 0.9
changes = 0
max_changes = 300
accepted_solutions = 0
while temp > min_temp:
     while changes < max_changes:
       new_state = Cal_SINR(random.randint(200,300) , random.randint(10,40))
       new_SINR = new_state[1]
       delta = new_SINR - Current_SINR
        if delta > 0:
          Current_SINR = new_SINR
          changes = changes +1
          accepted_solutions = accepted_solutions +1
       else:
        p = math.exp((delta*-1)/temp)     
        if random.random() < p:
            Current_SINR = new_SINR
            changes = changes +1
            accepted_solutions = accepted_solutions +1
        else:
            break

temp = temp * cooling
```

Answer (score 0):

well, if delta < 0 you still have a `Current_SINR = new_SINR` statement that will be executed with some probability, so in this case it will decrease.

Comment: yes I understand, but how can modify my code to get better results it loops and calculates the Cal_SINR function 300 times but doesn't reach optimized results most of the times. do I have something wrong with my code or understanding of the algorithm

Comment: @Mosalah that we cannot really answer - you need to try to identify a concrete issue you are having in order to get help here. For instance you were wondering why you sometimes get values lower, and the answer was that you assign the new value both in the delta >0 and delta <=0 branches of your if statement.